# Detecting memory leak in Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, runnable

I am working on a runnable that reads in input from a System stream and analyses the string that comes in, the program works well for a few days and then stops working, I am guessing it might be due to memory leak in my thread, but I cant seem to find it, can anyone suggest if there is something wrong with my code.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
        try {
            String inputStr;
            if ((inputStr = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //do something
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about stop working?

Comment: What does "stops working" mean?

Comment: It no longer block's IPs

Comment: Are you sure the threads are still running when the program "stops working"? How do you provide the standard input? From user interactive input, or is it a batch redirection? I suspect that an EOF of the standard input causes the program executes the `break` in your code, ending thus the thread.

Comment: Good point, I am using `fail -f -n 0 system.log | java -jar program.jar` to supply input, oh man I feel so blind, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the standard input is provided via a batch redirection, an EOF would cause the program execute the `break`, exiting the `while` loop and ending thus the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Change bufReader to this

```
InputStreamReader iSR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(iSR);
```

and close them like so:

```
bufReader.close();
iSR.close();
```

**Note:** Its the answer relevant to your memory leak problem if it exists.